# Backing up specific files and renaming them via Bash

Tags: bash, find, backup, exec, bitcoin

I want to create a backup script for my CryptoCurrency Wallets using bash. All wallets are in a subfolder of `/home`.

```
find /root/ -name 'wallet.dat' -exec cp {} /home/backup \;
```

This command copies the files; however, I want to do the following:

The wallets are always in a structure like this: `/home/<coinname>/.<coinname>/wallet.dat`.
And I want the backuped file to be named `<coinname>-wallet.dat` so the folder `/home/backup`
has following files:

- bitcoin-wallet.dat
- dogecoin-wallet.dat

and so on.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct adaptation of your command:

```
find /root/ -name 'wallet.dat' -execdir bash -c 'echo cp "$0" "/home/backup/${PWD##*/}-${0#\./}"' {} \;
```

**Explanation.**

- Each found file will be set as the 0-th positional argument for `bash`,
- with `execdir`, the `bash` process will be executed from the directory containing the found file, hence `$PWD` will expand to the containing directory,
- `${PWD##*/}` expands to the current directory, after removing everything up to and including the last slash (so, very likely, the basename of the containing directory),
- `${0#./}` expands to the name of the file found after removing the period and slash.

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Remove the word `echo` if it looks like what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name wallet.dat | while read x
do
   original="$x"
   # Strip filename off right end
   x=${x%/wallet.dat}
   # Strip all but last directory off left end
   x=${x##*/}
   newname="/home/backup/${x}-wallet.dat"
   echo cp "$original" "$newname"
done
```

Save the file above as `BackupWallets` and do this to run it:

```
chmod +x BackupWallets
./BackupWallets
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different way of doing something similar using `tar`:

```
find /root -name wallet.dat -print | tar -cv -T - -f /home/backup/wallets.tar
```

It uses `find` to find all files called `wallet.dat` and sends them to `tar` for copying into a tarfile in /home/backup.

Bear in mind that this only creates a single copy of your files, not a backup with several points in time that you can return to in case of loss - also that if your files get corrupted and your backup runs after the corruption but before you detect it, your backup will overwrite your good copies with corrupted ones... so it may be better to put the date in the tarfile name so you get a new one each time, like this:

```
find /root -name wallet.dat -print | tar -cv -T - -f "/home/backup/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')_wallets.tar"
```

then you will get a new file each day you run it called something like `/home/backup/2014-04-18_wallets.tar`